# Pin an element to another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

In a project, I need to pin an `position: absolute` element (child element) to another element (parent element), so if parent element move, I should change the position of child element also.

User clicks on a certain position of the page (assume a `div` with a text inside it, like a blog post or something), then I can get the element at that point or save the `x` and `y` position of the parent element into database.

When user come back to the same page, I should load existing pins and attach them to the parent elements, but the issue is that in a weblog or news portal, elements change frequently by adding or removing posts.

My question is how can I pin the child elements to parent elements and also detect the correct parent element and the change of parent elements also?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time, and post your code.

Comment: @Ejay I haven't tried anything, I'm looking for a solution to implement it actually.

Comment: First try (a lot), then ask.

Comment: I think the expectation of the site is that you have already tried something that didn't work. Then you post the example code. Then people try to help.

Comment: But to point you in the right direction, I think you want to look into jQuery to read the `$().position()` of the element then, then you will want to `$.ajax()` that data to your server. When the user data is sent to the client, you can move the stuff back to the correct position, using `$().css()`.

Comment: Try CSS selectors given in my answer. I hope it will helpful to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if parent is positionned as `relative`, child in `absolute` position will refer to that parent. Else it refers to the closest parent positionned, and by defaut to the window of browser (html).

`Position` can be for parent: `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed` in order to have child refers to this parent. It has a direct effect too to `z-index` rules, if triggered.

Answer (score 0):

A really simply way to accomplish this would be to give all of your parentelements a unique id and a common class, let's say they are an excerpt of an article and the class is called article.  Then you would create a click handler for your article class that pushes the article id in an array in the browser local storage AND appends your childelement with a common class, we'll call that favorite.

In your CSS for the article class, make sure the position is set to relative and your favorite class has it's position set to absolute (with whatever top/left/right/bottom values are appropriate).

Finally, create an onload handler for the page that reads the local storage array and appends the childelements to each of the articles with the id stored in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS selectors to pin an element with another:

```
.ele:before
.ele:after
```

e.g.:

```
.ele:after {
  right: 100%;
  top: 30px;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```